# Edit a theme file to limit post grab to a certain category (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress website using the theme OneEngine and it includes a really handy page builder, so it's great for noobs like me! Everything has been going fine until i tried to use the ET Blog Block which basically nicley shows a desired amount of the latest posts from ALL categories. Unfortunately it does not offer an option to pull the latest posts from a specific category or set of categories. This is the block file to edit and i have tried to add

> 'category' = 3

to the array query bit as i saw in another post on another site but that does not seem to work.
here is the relevant section of the php file that i believe needs changing.

```
    function block($instance) {
        extract($instance);
        $query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => $quantity,
            'category' => 3
    ));
    $i = 0;
    global $post;
    if($query->have_posts()){
        while($query->have_posts()){
            $query->the_post();
        $animation_effect   ='';
        $duration_effect    ='';
        more lines of code...
```

the reason for me doing this is to edit, rename and reuse this block multiple times so i can have a static front page with relevant sections which will show specific categories together. e.g.

--Injuries--
Recent posts from the injuries category to go here
--Some images--
--Transfer News--
Recent posts from the transfers category to go here

I posted this on the OneEngine theme forum but i received no replies and they're not as friendly as you guys!
Much appreciated.

Comment: What isn't working exactly?  Are you sure that '3' is the ID of the category you want to restrict?  If you don't know or don't want to use the ID of the category, you can always use the name as well.

Comment: @JasonRoman currently this blog block is displaying posts from all of my categories even with 'category' = 3. I want only the posts from category 3 to show. How would I go about using the name? Thanks

Comment: @JasonRoman managed to fix it! just used 'category_name' instead of just 'category'. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used 'category_name' instead of trying to link to the category id.
Problem solved!

Comment: Interesting, so did you actually pass the name instead of the id?

Comment: Cool.  I have a feeling you were retrieving the category id incorrectly and that's why it didn't work.  Regardless, passing the name just works as well :)

Comment: @JasonRoman that's most likely the case! I tried with both 'category' and 'category_id' but neither option worked